# Line Chart in swift 3

Tags: xcode, charts, swift3

Im trying to create a line chart with this code. I've laid out most of the code I've been messing around with it for hours trying different things.
In class:

```
PendingViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate
```

Outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!

ViewDidLoad:
    let months = ["Jan" , "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    let dollars1 = [1453.0,2352,5431,1442,5451,6486,1173,5678,9234,1345,9411,2212]
    self.lineChartView.delegate = self
    // 2
    self.lineChartView.descriptionText = "Tap node for details"
    // 3
    self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.textColor = UIColor.white
    self.lineChartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    // 4
    self.lineChartView.noDataText = "No data provided"
    // 5
    setChartData(months: months)
```

Func:

```
func setChartData(months : [String]) {

    // 1 - creating an array of data entries
    var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for i in 0 ..< months.count {
        yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: dollars1[i], y: Double(i)))
    }

    // 2 - create a data set with our array
    let set1: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: yVals1, label: "First Set")
    set1.axisDependency = .left // Line will correlate with left axis values
    set1.setColor(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)) // our line's opacity is 50%
    set1.setCircleColor(UIColor.red) // our circle will be dark red
    set1.lineWidth = 2.0
    set1.circleRadius = 6.0 // the radius of the node circle
    set1.fillAlpha = 65 / 255.0
    set1.fillColor = UIColor.red
    set1.highlightColor = UIColor.white
    set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = true

    //3 - create an array to store our LineChartDataSets
    var dataSets : [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()
    dataSets.append(set1)

    //4 - pass our months in for our x-axis label value along with our dataSets
    let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: months, dataSets: dataSets)
    data.setValueTextColor(UIColor.white)

    //5 - finally set our data
    self.lineChartView.data = data


}
```

Im receiving this error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for typel 'LineChartData' with an argument list of type '(xVals: [String], dataSets: [LineChartDataSet])'
```

Thank You,

Denis

Comment: Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you add the link of library.

Comment: pod 'Charts'? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Is using pods a good practice in your opinion?

Comment: There is no issue with pod, I was just asking about the chart library I got it you are using Library with name Charts. Let me check that one will respond you.

Comment: I have found the issue regarding error `LineChartData` has init that accept only `dataSets` So it should be like     `let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)`

Comment: Ok I see. So did you look into the library to find that LineChartData only accepts "datasets"

Comment: I've only been coding for 2 months now and I'm still really new

Comment: @Nirav D Now I get an error at .animate error is "BAD ACCESS"

Comment: I haven't used that library so don't know about it may be you need to ask a new question for that.

Comment: **Herr is Working Code for (Swift 4)** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612972/10150796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hint for how you can figure out the overloads and I use all the time.  In the "Find Navigator" in xCode you can search for "class LineChartData" -- then you can go examine the code in your pod where the "LineChartData" class is defined and see what arguments are in its init methods.  Anyway, the answer I believe, base on this would be to change the line where you say:

```
 let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: months, dataSets: dataSets)
```

to THIS

```
 let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
```

This matches the available overloads. If too late for you, above may help somebody else.

Comment: Can you help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958478/line-graph-model-swift-3

Answer (score 3):

Working code snippet: (Swift 3.0 and Chart 3.0)

```
fileprivate func setChart(_ lineChartView: LineChartView, dataPoints: [Double], values: [Double]) {    
  var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

  for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
    let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
  }

  let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Altitude")
  lineChartDataSet.setColor(UIColor.blue)
  // lineChartDataSet.drawCubicEnabled = true
  lineChartDataSet.mode = .cubicBezier
  lineChartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
  lineChartDataSet.lineWidth = 1.0
  lineChartDataSet.circleRadius = 5.0
  lineChartDataSet.highlightColor = UIColor.red
  lineChartDataSet.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true

  var dataSets = [IChartDataSet]()
  dataSets.append(lineChartDataSet)

  let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)

  lineChartView.data = lineChartData
}
```