# Passing data with InstantiateViewController

Tags: xcode, swift3

I have this code however, I'm not receiving the data in the second view controller... What am I doing wrong here?

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PostSubmit", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostSubmitVC") as! PostSubmitViewController {
            let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            vc.filteredResult = filteredResult
        }
        self.present(nc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Print `filteredResult` before you pass it. Maybe it's nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be the problem is you are presenting wrong controller `nc` value you have set is inside the block and it is not available out side that block.

```
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostSubmitVC") as! PostSubmitViewController 
 let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
 vc.filteredResult = filteredResult 
 self.present(nc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Yeah it is man, thank you for all of your help!! I really appreciate it. Seems like its always something so small that I over look. I literally tore apart my code today for something so small. lol

Comment: @Denis Welcome mate :)

Comment: My bad dude, I was trying to post this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607702/line-chart-in-swift-3 but thanks for the reminder. Any help on this would be awesome. Its from another source online, but I had trouble converting it to swift 3

Comment: @Denis You want help with that question?

Comment: Yeah if you could.

Comment: @Denis let me check If possible will give solution.